# Return integer value of age(date) function in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I would like to determine the number of days that an account has been open.
Ideally, I would like to compare the return value to an integer(days).
i.e

I would like to see if age(open_date) > 14

If anyone has any better ideas...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you get the number of days comparing two dates:

```
SQL> select extract(day from now()-'2015-02-21'::timestamptz);
 date_part
-----------
       122
(1 row)
```

Comment: This worked really well :)


"extract(day from current_date-open_date::timestamptz)= 14"

I wanted to ask what the 'tz' at the end of timestamp meant?

Comment: timestamp with TIME ZONE